# Identify rows containing repeating customers and assigning them new id as per serial number generated in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

| id | repeat customer id | store | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A | 07-19-22 |
| 2 |  | A | 07-19-22 |
| 3 |  | A | 07-19-22 |

| id | repeat customer id | store | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | B | 07-19-22 |
| 2 |  | B | 07-19-22 |
| 3 | 1 | B | 07-19-22 |
| 4 |  | B | 07-19-22 |

and more tables from other store

The problem here is

1. all stores start with id 1
2. repeat customer have new id in id column and their original id is retained in repeat customer id column

I have to concatenated all the tables and also keep track of repeating customer for analytics. I have joined all tables using `UNION ALL` and also created a dummy id column using `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NEW_ID, * FROM CTE`, but I have no clue how to capture and assign value to repeat customer id such that I get the table as below

| NEW_ID | id | new_repeat_customer_id | repeat customer id | store | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  | A | 07-19-22 |
| 2 | 2 |  |  | A | 07-19-22 |
| 3 | 3 |  |  | A | 07-19-22 |
| 4 | 1 |  |  | B | 07-19-22 |
| 5 | 2 |  |  | B | 07-19-22 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 | 1 | B | 07-19-22 |
| 7 | 4 |  |  | B | 07-19-22 |

Comment: sql server but data is present in postgres(staging server)

Comment: sql server will be good

Comment: @DaleK i have removed the tag for postgres and also edited the ques. Thank you.

Comment: "I have joined all tables using `UNION ALL`" - a union is _not_ a join: it's a concatenation.

Comment: @ Dai i concatenate the tables

Comment: Why store your data like this? Why not store them all in one table if they all contain the same schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to incorporate it, would be to use Alphanumeric String as NEW_ID, and `concat` STORE and ID to create NEW_ID. For example `A_000000001`. In that way you can add similar STORE to REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID as well.

So in this case, instead of `NEW_ID`=6, you would have `NEW_ID`=`B_000000003` and `REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID` would become `B_000000001`.

But in case that is not possible, you can use query like below to get the output

[DB Fiddle Query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=cbe63994b10f9e3b0eff53b0c89d463a)

```
with CTE as
(
select * from STORE1 
UNION ALL
select * from STORE2
)

,CTE2 as
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NEW_ID,t.* from CTE t)

,REPEAT_ID as 
(select NEW_ID,ID,REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID,STORE from CTE2 where REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID is not null)

,REPEACT_CUSTOMER_ID as 
(select c.NEW_ID as NEW_REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID,r.NEW_ID
from REPEAT_ID r
left join CTE2 c
on c.ID=r.REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID and c.STORE=r.STORE
)

select c.* , n.NEW_REPEAT_CUSTOMER_ID
from CTE2 c
left join REPEACT_CUSTOMER_ID n
on c.NEW_ID=n.NEW_ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=cbe63994b10f9e3b0eff53b0c89d463a

SO basically you have to separate rows where REPEATE customer is present and join it with main table query.